# How to get params from select form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code in my view:

```
<% select("post", "person_id", Person.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {include_blank: true }) %>
```

I want to get value of `post[:person_id]` from params.

When I am trying

```
@person_Select = params[:post[person_id]]
```

I am getting error.

Comment: Add the log file with related request.

Comment: @Mohammad look in your server and past code what you get in params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use below way to get your params in controller:

```
@selected_person = params[:post][:person_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing it the wrong way.

It should be:

```
@person_Select = params[:post][:person_id]
```

Instead of:

```
@person_Select = params[:post[person_id]]
```

Answer (score 0):

here this should be syntax error 
instead of this

```
@person_Select = params[:post[person_id]]
```

you have to write

```
@person_Select = params[:post][person_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

should use `params[:post][:person_id]`